# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have a problem when try to deploy my app to the hosting via gem Capistrano.

I have next error list:

```
   (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
    cap aborted!
    SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru: rake exit status: 1
```

My deploy.rb file is:

```
lock '3.4.0'

    application = 'yurta24'
    login = 'yurta24'
    $user = 'hosting_' + login
    $server = 'calcium.locum.ru'
    rvm_ruby_string = '2.1.5p273'
    deploy_to = "/home/#{ $user }/projects/#{ application }"
    unicorn_conf = "/etc/unicorn/#{ application }.#{ login }.rb"
    unicorn_pid = "/var/run/unicorn/#{ $user }/#{ application }.#{ login }.pid"
    unicorn_start_cmd = "(cd #{ deploy_to }/current; rvm use #{ rvm_ruby_string } do bundle exec unicorn_rails -Dc #{ unicorn_conf })"

    set :application, application 
    set :repo_url, "https://github.com/verrom/yurta24.git"
    set :deploy_to, deploy_to
    set :pty, true
    set :default_env, { path: "xxxxx" }
    namespace :deploy do

      after :restart, :clear_cache do
        on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
        end
      end
```

My production.rb file is:

```
connect_to = "#{$user}@#{$server}"
role :app, [connect_to]
role :web, [connect_to]
role :db,  [connect_to]
set :enable_ssl, true
```

Full updated error report after updating database.yml is:

```
verevkinra@ubuntu:~/apps/yurta24$ cap production deploy
DEBUG [191cfb48] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [191cfb48] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru's password:xxxxxxxxxxx
DEBUG [191cfb48] Finished in 5.999 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [cba4e265] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/rvm ] as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [cba4e265] Command: [ -d /usr/local/rvm ]
DEBUG [cba4e265] Finished in 0.171 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [363e1014] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm version as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [363e1014] Command: ( PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm version )
DEBUG [363e1014]    rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
DEBUG [363e1014] Finished in 0.374 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
DEBUG [0810a260] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm current as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [0810a260] Command: ( PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm current )
DEBUG [0810a260]    system
DEBUG [0810a260] Finished in 0.391 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
system
DEBUG [769f1945] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [769f1945] Command: ( PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version )
DEBUG [769f1945]    ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
DEBUG [769f1945]    
DEBUG [769f1945] Finished in 0.605 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
INFO [b1cf993c] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/yurta24/ as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [b1cf993c] Command: ( PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/yurta24/ )
INFO [b1cf993c] Finished in 0.170 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/yurta24/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru: scp: /tmp/yurta24/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied

scp: /tmp/yurta24/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied

Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru: scp: /tmp/yurta24/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied
verevkinra@ubuntu:~/apps/yurta24$ git checkout
M   config/deploy.rb
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the full error report? When does this fail? Does it go through a particular capistrano recipe before it fails?

Comment: Also try $cap production deploy:check , and does report the same error there?

Comment: @moeabdo, hi. I've update my question. Yes, it goes through a particular capistrano recipe before it fails. Yes, I suppose, error is the same.

Comment: can you show you database.yml "ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter"

Comment: @moeabdol, I've update a question.

Answer (score 1):

So capistrano is reporting that you're missing the database adapter in you database.yml production. You seem to have misplaced postgresql as the database name instead of the adapter name.

In you database.yml your should have the following:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: you_app_name_production
  username: yourdatabaseusername #in most cases this will be postgres
  password: youdatabasepassword
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

And in your Gemfile make sure you have sqlite gem in development and test gourp, and postgres gem (pg) in produciton, something like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  # all your other dev and test gems
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# outsite your developement and test group add this
gem 'pg'
```

Now! run `bundle install` then `cap production deploy:check` to see if everything went well. You might need to configure you remote server postgres for a username and password.

If your facing further troubles, you can follow [this](http://www.travisluong.com/ruby-on-rails-nginx-unicorn-postgresql-capistrano/) complete guide on how to deploy a Rails 4 application (Nginx + Capistrano + Unicorn) to your Ubuntu VPS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesnt work.. I've update my question. in database.yml I've change you_app_name_production to DB name, what gived to me hoster, am I right?

Comment: it should be yurta24_production

Comment: I've change you_app_name_production to yurta24_production, and the error is the same.

Comment: Sorry, error is another. I've update logs in the question.

Comment: You seem to have permission issues! Have you tried to follow the tutorial I'v linked in my answer?

Comment: yes, I tried. I've setup SSH-keys. But the problem is the same

Comment: Does it succeed when you "cap production deploy:check"? and when you "cap production deploy" capistrano prompts you to enter your password, right?